# Python3 Requests - Not Working

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, curl, python-requests

I would like to submit a POST request using Python, preferably Python3.
The problem is, the server must be blocking the request somehow (even with proper headers and cookies etc).

To see for yourself, simply go to this link, fill out any phone number and email, and hit submit. I wish to replicate this, even if I need to use robobrowser or something (which won't work either).

https://sprint-locator.safely.com/signupBasicInformation.htm

I have also tried replicating it with cURL, nothing.

```
import requests

payload = {'email': 'admin%40dr.com', 'emailConfirm': 'admin%40dr.com', 'phoneNumber.areaCode': '302', 'phoneNumber.prefix': '750', 'phoneNumber.line': '1213'}
url='https://sprint-locator.safely.com/signupBasicInformation.htm'
r = requests.post(url, payload)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: So you *can* submit the request from the form but *not* from either cURL or Python/requests?

Comment: @Dylan please provide with a valid Sprint phone (and e-mail maybe?) since I'm being redirected to https://sprint-locator.safely.com/signUpAccountSuspended.htm

Comment: I have noticed that if I set the User-Agent header using a valid Firefox user agent I get a different page to what I get if I don't set a header if that is interesting.

Comment: I am checking to see if a phone number is valid or not.
When you submit the form with a random number, it will land you on an error page saying it is invalid.

I will post a valid number, but it is pointless.
Email: admin@dr.com
Phone: 302-750-1213 - the goal is to get "invalid number" error.

Comment: https://sprint-locator.safely.com/signUpAccountSuspended.htm
This is the goal, however with requests I am sent to a login page on a different subdomain.

Comment: Once O add a user-agent I get to the page `Sprint Family Locator : We've Encountered a Problem` using my own email address so the data is getting posted. Are you sure your login details are correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some sites require "proper" `User-agent`, for security reasons (sic!), to filter out bots (and more) allowing only browser clients.

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'}
payload = {'email': 'admin%40dr.com', 'emailConfirm': 'admin%40dr.com', 'phoneNumber.areaCode': '302', 'phoneNumber.prefix': '750', 'phoneNumber.line': '1213'}
url='https://sprint-locator.safely.com/signupBasicInformation.htm'
r = requests.post(url, payload, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: This is true, I have already tested it with user agents and gotten here.
The problem is, all that did was fill in the form, and it never submitted.

If it worked properly, you would have been sent to:
https://sprint-locator.safely.com/signUpAccountSuspended.htm

I really appreciate your time @kwarunek